# Twilio Speech Recognition Issues with SpeechResult

Tags: c#, twilio, speech-recognition

I have this project, I need to call to one of my numbers in Twilio, say something and after the user response with his voice play an audio, I already "have" the code but the SpeechResult and UnstableSpeechResults always comes null. This is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceiveCall()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();

        var gather = new Gather(input: new List<Gather.InputEnum> { Gather.InputEnum.Speech }, 
            action: new Uri("http://eb4cdc87.ngrok.io/Voice/GatherProcess"), 
            speechTimeout: "5",
            method: HttpMethod.Post,
            partialResultCallback: new Uri("http://eb4cdc87.ngrok.io/Voice/WriteVoice") , 
            partialResultCallbackMethod: HttpMethod.Post);
        gather.Say("Say Something to record and after press pound");
        gather.Pause(5);
        gather.Play(new Uri("https://corn-collie-1715.twil.io/assets/demo.mp3"));
        response.Append(gather);

        return TwiML(response);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void GatherProcess()
    {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        var gather = new Gather(input: new List<Gather.InputEnum> { Gather.InputEnum.Speech, Gather.InputEnum.Dtmf });//(input: "speech dtmf", timeout: 3, numDigits: 1);  
        gather.Say("You say this: " + Request.QueryString["SpeechResult"].ToString());
        gather.Pause(5);
        gather.Play(new Uri("https://corn-collie-1715.twil.io/assets/demo.mp3"));
        response.Append(gather);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void WriteVoice()
    {
        var speech = Request.QueryString["UnstableSpeechResult"].ToString();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(speech))
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Content/", "Voice.txt")), "You entered: " + speech + "\n");
        }


    }
```

I really need help on this, I know I'm missing something but I dont know what is it, I'm starting with twilio so I have not much experience.

Thanks

Comment: What is the TwiML that your first endpoint, with the `<Gather>`, is returning? Do you find you are getting a `Digits` parameter sent to your action URL?

Comment: at first my first endpoint return a TwiML object but the I always got the error because Request.QueryString["SpeechResult"] or Request.QueryString["UnstableSpeechResult"] come null I guess that is not the problem..

Comment: and also ["Digits"] comes null. Thanks @philnash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally works!

The solution was use Request["SpeechResult"] and not Request.QueryString["SpeechResult"].

Thanks

Comment: I was about to suggest this, glad you got there first. Be aware that `POST` data is likely not in the query string, but part of the POST body.